# postgres: function with select and notify

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, publish-subscribe

So, I have a table which describes positions of some entities in space(for simplicity in one dimension, original problem is related )

```
    CREATE TABLE positions(
       id VARCHAR (32) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
       position VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
    );
```

And I create a trigger which notifies on every update

```
  CREATE TRIGGER position_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON positions
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_position();
```

and a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION notify_position() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify(
      'positions',
      TG_TABLE_NAME || ',id,' || NEW.id || ',position,' || NEW.position
    );
    RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

how can I change the function to notify only when there are few entities in the same position.

e.g. consider a table after update

```
id  |positions
-------------
id1 |10
id2 |10
id3 |11
```

I need to call notify with a string 'id1,id2'

Probably, I need to select somehow all the entities which have the same position as updated one and create a list of them(a string which contains comma-separated ids). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, you want the following to happen when an entity's position is updated:

- If no entities are currently in the new position, do nothing.
- Otherwise call notify with a comma-separated list of entity IDs that are currently in the new position.

You can achieve this in your trigger function by using the `string_agg` aggregation function to construct a list of IDs of matching entities, then checking its length before calling `pg_notify`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION notify_position() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  colocated_ids TEXT;
BEGIN
  -- Construct list of IDs of co-located entities.
  colocated_ids := (
    SELECT string_agg(id, ',')
    FROM positions
    WHERE position = NEW.position AND id != NEW.id
  );

  -- Notify listeners if some co-located entities were found.
  IF length(colocated_ids) > 0 THEN
    PERFORM pg_notify('positions', colocated_ids);
  END IF;

  RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that without the `AND id != NEW.id` check, the ID of the updated entity will also appear in the list. You could avoid this by making this trigger fire `BEFORE UPDATE` instead of `AFTER UPDATE`.

Comment: I also found a solution with for-loop. But your answer looks better. Thx!